# VBA If Then combined with For Each Loop

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone advise on the following, please?

I have this For loop in the following way but I need to add another condition ("If" I suppose)(see comment):

```
**'if cell in "A2:A1000" = "cat" and is not empty then run this:**

    For Each cel In .Range("D2:D1000") 
    
    Time = cel.Value
    If Not IsEmpty(Time) Then
    
    'code does some stuff
    
        End If
    Next

**'Else if cell in "A2:A1000" <> "cat" but not blank run this:**

'some code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub forfor()
        
Dim SrchRng As Range, celq As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("A1:A1000")
        
For Each celq In SrchRng
If InStr(1, celq.Value, "cat") > 0 Then
    
    For Each cel In .Range("D2:D1000") 
    Time = cel.Value
    If Not IsEmpty(Time) Then
    'code does some stuff
    End If
    Next

End If
Next celq
    
End Sub
```

Comment: nested For Each ?

Comment: Not sure but it isn't working properly. I thought my earlier solution worked but it didn't and I have deleted it.